# What causes two UITableViewCells with the same autolayout constraints to behave differently?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout, uicollectionview

I'm working with the [AFCollectionView](https://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell/) in a table and it is not rendering as I would expect.  In an effort to debug the issue I created another custom table cell with the desired layout and put it into the AFCollectionView cells.  The collection view cells are still not rendering correctly.

Both of these cells were built with no xib or storyboard so I'm struggling to try to debug the autolayout console issues. I understand that a UICollectionView is more complex than a UIView but i'm not sure where to even begin trying to make changes given the issues displayed.

[image]

Both cells have the following updateConstraints method called from inside of `- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier` method.

```
    [self updateConstraints];
    return self;
}

- (void)updateConstraints{
    [super updateConstraints];

    //Create local versions of the ivars
    UILabel *titleLabelP = self.titleLabel;
    UIView *bottomViewP = self.collectionView;
    NSNumber *bottomViewHeightP = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:self.bottomViewHeight];


    //Build the visual constraints
    NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(titleLabelP, bottomViewP);
    NSDictionary *metrics = @{ @"padding" : @8.0, @"viewHeight": bottomViewHeightP };

    // title and bottom view fill the width of the superview (cell content view)
    [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-padding-[titleLabelP]-padding-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
    [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-padding-[bottomViewP]-padding-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
    // title and bottom view are setup vertically with 8px of padding between.  The cell should expand to fit the full size of the bottom view.
    [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-padding-[titleLabelP]-padding-[bottomViewP(viewHeight)]-padding-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];

}
```

CONSOLE LOG OF AUTOLAYOUT ISSUES:

```
2016-11-21 14:19:06.423003 AutoLayoutTableCellTest[71645:4731377] [Warning] Warning once only: Detected a case where constraints ambiguously suggest a height of zero for a tableview cell's content view. We're considering the collapse unintentional and using standard height instead.
2016-11-21 14:19:06.425136 AutoLayoutTableCellTest[71645:4731377] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x608000096710 h=--& v=--& UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fb87ac1a770.midY == 22.25   (active)>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x6080000966c0 h=--& v=--& UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fb87ac1a770.height == 44.5   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000095860 V:|-(8)-[UILabel:0x7fb87ac1b670'CURRENT INDEXPATH ROW: 1']   (active, names: '|':AFTableViewCell:0x7fb87b050400'CellIdentifier' )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000095900 AFIndexedCollectionView:0x7fb87b051000.height == 150   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000095950 V:[AFIndexedCollectionView:0x7fb87b051000]-(8)-|   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fb87ac1a770 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000095fe0 V:[UILabel:0x7fb87ac1b670'CURRENT INDEXPATH ROW: 1']-(8)-[AFIndexedCollectionView:0x7fb87b051000]   (active)>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x608000095180 h=-&- v=--& 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Top' AFTableViewCell:0x7fb87b050400'CellIdentifier'.minY == 0   (active, names: '|':UITableViewWrapperView:0x7fb87b03b800 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000095fe0 V:[UILabel:0x7fb87ac1b670'CURRENT INDEXPATH ROW: 1']-(8)-[AFIndexedCollectionView:0x7fb87b051000]   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2016-11-21 14:19:06.425934 AutoLayoutTableCellTest[71645:4731377] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x608000096710 h=--& v=--& UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fb87ac1a770.midY == 22.25   (active)>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x6080000966c0 h=--& v=--& UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fb87ac1a770.height == 44.5   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000095860 V:|-(8)-[UILabel:0x7fb87ac1b670'CURRENT INDEXPATH ROW: 1']   (active, names: '|':AFTableViewCell:0x7fb87b050400'CellIdentifier' )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6080000958b0 V:[UILabel:0x7fb87ac1b670'CURRENT INDEXPATH ROW: 1']-(8)-[AFIndexedCollectionView:0x7fb87b051000]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000095900 AFIndexedCollectionView:0x7fb87b051000.height == 150   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000095950 V:[AFIndexedCollectionView:0x7fb87b051000]-(8)-|   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fb87ac1a770 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x608000095180 h=-&- v=--& 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Top' AFTableViewCell:0x7fb87b050400'CellIdentifier'.minY == 0   (active, names: '|':UITableViewWrapperView:0x7fb87b03b800 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6080000958b0 V:[UILabel:0x7fb87ac1b670'CURRENT INDEXPATH ROW: 1']-(8)-[AFIndexedCollectionView:0x7fb87b051000]   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

I've put the sample project on github @ https://github.com/propstm/AutoLayoutTableCellTest

EDIT TO SHOW INIT FOR CELL WITH COLLECTIONVIEW:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    if (!(self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier])) return nil;

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 9, 10);
    layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(100, 100);

    layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical;
    self.collectionView = [[AFIndexedCollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero collectionViewLayout:layout];
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:CollectionViewCellIdentifier];
    [self.collectionView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:FALSE];
    self.collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.collectionView];
    if(!self.titleLabel){
        self.titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(16, 8, self.frame.size.width-8, 20)];
        [self.titleLabel setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:FALSE];
        UIFont *boldFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@".SFUIText-Bold" size:16.0f];
        [self.titleLabel setFont:boldFont];
        [self addSubview:self.titleLabel];
    }

    self.bottomViewHeight = 150;

    [self updateConstraints];
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get these Auto Layout warnings to go away with the following changes:

- In your `AFTableViewCell`’s `-initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` method, before returning, set the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` property of the cell’s `contentView` to `NO`.
- Add the title label to the cell’s content view, not the cell itself.

This causes a new warning to appear:

```
[Warning] Warning once only: Detected a case where constraints ambiguously suggest a height of zero for a tableview cell's content view. We're considering the collapse unintentional and using standard height instead.
```

However, the layout seems much closer to what you intended.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you create a view and set auto layout constraints programmatically, you have to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` on the view you added constraints. If not, the autoresizing mask will translated to auto layout constraints.

In this case, you need to add like:

```
self.titleLabel.translateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
self.collectionView.translateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

**Added**

According to the log you added, the collectionView's height is 150 but the contentView's height is smaller than that. You have to return the correct height of `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: i'd had that part up above in the cell's init method.  I've added that code to the post as well.  I tried replacing NO with FALSE, still no resolution.

Comment: I'm using estimated row heights.  The titleLabel has a height of 20, the height of the collectionView is 150, so with my vertical constraint I'm expecting the auto-sized height to be about 200.

Comment: You also have paddings. Return the exact height of sum of all heights and paddings